# php if isset _GET chapter or marker

Tags: php, variables, get, templating, isset

I have an **index.php** and in it I want to generate the page template it should show.
So when you're on **index.php** you see the **home.php** template.

If you're on the **index.php?chapter=chapter-name** you see the **chapter.php** template.
And if you're on the **index.php?marker=marker-name** you see the **marker.php** template.

I now have the following:

```
<?php
    if(!isset($_GET["chapter"])){
        $page = "root";
        include_once('view/home.php');
    } else {
        $page = $_GET["chapter"];
        switch($page){
            case "chapter-name":
            include_once('view/chapter.php');
            break;

            case "marker-name":
            include_once('view/marker.php');
            break;
        }
    }
?>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Any problem in existing code? What is your question?

Comment: are you giving answer or question here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//Array of configuration views
$config_template = array(
    'default' => 'view/home.php' ,
    'chapter-name' => 'view/chapter.php' ,
    'marker-name' => 'view/marker.php' ,
) ;
//Logic to call template
$include = $config_template['default'] ;
if ( isset( $_GET['chapter'] ) && array_key_exists( strtolower( $_GET['chapter'] ) , $config_template ) ) {
    $include = $config_template[$_GET['chapter']] ;
}
else if ( isset( $_GET['marker'] ) && array_key_exists( strtolower( $_GET['marker'] ) , $config_template ) ) {
    $include = $config_template[$_GET['marker']] ;
}
//include template
include_once($include) ;
```

This way the code is ready to grow up...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want something like this ?

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET["chapter"])) {
    $page = $_GET["chapter"];
    include_once('view/chapter.php');
} else if(isset($_GET["marker"])) {
    $page = $_GET["marker"];
    include_once('view/marker.php');
} else {
    $page = "root";
    include_once('view/home.php');
}
?>
```

With `$_GET["chapter"]` you will never get 'marker-name' because it is in `$_GET["marker"]`

Answer (score 0):

i think you want  something like this

```
<?php
    if(isset($_GET["chapter"]) && $_GET["chapter"]=='chapter-name')
    {
        $page = $_GET["chapter"];
        include_once('view/chapter.php');
    }
    else if(isset($_GET["marker"]) && $_GET["marker"]=='marker-name')
    {
        $page = $_GET["marker"];
        include_once('view/marker.php');
    }
    else
    {
        $page = "root";
        include_once('view/home.php');
    }
?>
```